# Showing a custom UIAlertView in place of default UIAlertViews for In App Purchases?

Tags: ios, objective-c, in-app-purchase, uialertview

An In App purchase consists of three default alert views provided by Apple:

First One:

```
Confirm Your In-App Purchase

Do you want to buy one {product name} for ${productPrice}

Buttons: [Cancel] [Buy]
```

Second One (If already purchased):

```
Youve already purchased this. Would you like to get it again for free?

Buttons: [Cancel] [OK]
```

Last One:

```
Thank You

Your purchase was successful.

Buttons: [OK]
```

My question is am I able to replace these with my own custom (better looking) alert views than the default one's that Apple provides us? If so, how could I detect which UIAlertView is being displayed and would this be against Apple's guidelines using custom ones for In App Purchases as long as the messages are almost identically the same?

Comment: No. For security reasons these are generated by the system. As far as I know they don't even run in the app context. It would be really dangerous if developers could access these alerts and change the messages to something that is almost identically. e.g. "Do you want to buy x for $0.99" instead of the original "Do you want to buy x for $999.99"

Comment: That is a good point Matthias. Never thought about that!

Comment: Down votes should have to provide a reason why it was down voted...

Comment: And also from iOS 8 there are no more UIAlertView (its deprecated), now we only see UIAlertController from iOS..!!

Comment: SO discourages providing information about down votes mainly due to revenge down voting, sad but true.